# why when I add secure-ls to vuex-persistedstate the vuex information does not have the session data as it was before?

Tags: vue.js, security, vuex

Previously when I had not configured secure-ls as it is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/7l9wb

in my localStorage in the 'vuex' key I had more or less the following

```
{authUser:{name:'My name', authenticated: true}}
```

after having configured secure-sl in the vuex-persistedstate:

```
 storage: {
        getItem: key => ls.get(key),
        setItem: (key, value) => ls.set(key, value),
        removeItem: key => ls.remove(key)
      }
```

When I reload the page, the page appears blank, since the vuex values ​​have been reset. If I then comment out the secure-sl setting:

```
/*storage: {
            getItem: key => ls.get(key),
            setItem: (key, value) => ls.set(key, value),
            removeItem: key => ls.remove(key)
          }*/
```

and I refresh the page again, the localStorage values ​​are:

```
{authUser:{name: null, authenticated: false}}
```

please note that name is null and authenticated is false

Behavior that seems strange to me, this only happens when the user is logged in and before applying the secure-sl, since if I do it from incognito mode with a new session and the configuration of the secure-sl I do not have any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an issue with vuex-persistedstore.

It is is deprecated anyway, so stop using it. You can use Vuex.subscribe() instead:
https://www.mikestreety.co.uk/blog/vue-js-using-localstorage-with-the-vuex-store/